# How can I get appended columns in model to array?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue

How can I get appended columns in model to array?

```php
$ticket = Ticket::create([
  'assigned_user_id' => $request->assigned_user_id,
  'creator_id' => $request->creator_id,
  'description' => $request->description,
  'type' => $request->type,
  'status' => Ticket::CREATED,
]);
   
flash(__('tickets.ticket_created_successfully'))->success();
    
$data = $ticket->refresh()->toArray();
return $data;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$ticket>refresh()->toArray();` to `$ticket->toArray();` I don't think you need to refresh your model in this case.
Read more about serializing to array [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-serialization#serializing-to-arrays)
in the official docs of Laravel.